# Json - checking child node null value

Tags: javascript, json

How can i check if a child attribute of a json object is null? While firefox recognizes it, Chrome and IE 8 don't.

I have a json object like this:

```
centralData.phone.id;
centralData.address.id;
centralData.product.id;
//and many others
```

And i'd like to check if some of it's attributes might be null. I'm doing this and it works:

```
if(centralData.phone != null){
   //Do things
}
```

But this don't, since it's not always i have a StockGroup

```
if(centralData.product.StockGroup != null){
 //Error
}
```

**So, how can i check if `centralData.product.StockGroup`  is null?**

Comment: What are you trying to check exactly?

Comment: Nitpicking: You don't have a "JSON object". You have an object or you have JSON. The latter is a data format and nothing but a STRING.

Comment: I just edited to make more clear. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @Mörre I didn't know it wasn't called json object. Guess i mistook it because of java's class JSONObject.

Comment: For your 2nd example, if centralData.product does not exist, OF COURSE you get an error. You have to check like this: "if(centralData.product && centralData.product.StockGroup != null)" It IS a little inconvenient, but you have to check ALL ELEMENTS of the path individually and not just the leaf element of the tree structure. Not to mention that you should use !== (or ===) and be clear if you want to check null or undefined.

Comment: @Mörre I can't it directly, apparently. While it works on Firefox, it doesn't on IE 8. I already tried to check `centralData.product.StockGroup != null` and IE 8 says that it's null or not an object.

Comment: I told you why (it could be). More help is impossible if you don't give us a COMPLETE example, esp. what is the value of centralData.product in your last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to check if it's `null`, you want to check if the property exists (it would be `undefined` in this case). Your check works because you are using `==` instead of `===`, which converts between types (`undefined == null`, but `undefined !== null`).

When you want to check for a nested property, you need to check every level. I would recommend to use the `in` operator, as it checks if the property exists and ignores it's value.

This does what you want to do:

```
if("product" in centralData && "StockGroup" in centralData.product){
    …
}
```

Comment: @FB55 It worked. However i have to initialize the product property or i get a `centralData.product is not a object`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you would check if a property is `undefined` instead

```
if(typeof (centralData.product || {}).StockGroup) !== "undefined") {
   /* do something */
}
```

this kind of check [was described on ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-safety-fence-for-your-property-lookups) site and the overall code is much shorter

Comment: Really interesting. This works too, but i find @FB55 answer more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using null, try comparing your object with undefined.

Comment: Like `if(centralData.product.StockGroup != 'undefined')`? Will that work on any case? I've seen some posts over the net which says that 'undefined' is not a reliable way to check for null objects.

Comment: Of course, "undefined" checks for "undefined" not for null. That's why I said in my comment to the Q to be clear what you check for. "undefined" means "does not (even) exist", null DOES exist and DOES have a value, which is "null". VERY different.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't make myself very clear: to see if StockGroup exists you can try this: `if(centralData.product.StockGroup)`

Comment: @Mörre Thanks for you explanation, i didn't know the exact difference between 'undefined' and null.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript employs [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), you can perform checks like this with no detriment to performance:

```
if(centralData.product != null && centralData.product.StockGroup != null){

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I tried a few minutes ago. Strangely, firefox can understand it, but not Chrome or IE

Comment: Show your code, there's nothing wrong with this, so it must be something else you're doing...